# mysql 8.0 in-memory table slow insert

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Please help with following strange issue.I defined in memory table but insert of 600.000 rows takes 13 minutes and causes heavy write to disk. The CPU is underutilized and I have enough free memory. What's wrong and why I see the I/O?
1. I defined max_heap_table_size as 1GB and restarted the DB.
2. I created the table as:

```
CREATE TABLE `data`
     (
       `id`         bigint(20)       DEFAULT NULL,
       `datetime`   timestamp        DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       `channel`    int(11)          DEFAULT NULL,
       `value`      bigint(20)       DEFAULT NULL
     ) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

3. I created the procedure to insert data.

> ```
> DELIMITER $$
> CREATE PROCEDURE generate_data()
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
>   WHILE i < 600001 DO
>     INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `datetime`,`value`,`channel`) VALUES (
>       i,
>       FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 01:00:00')+FLOOR(RAND()*31536000)),
>       ROUND(RAND()*100,2),
>       i
>     );
>     SET i = i + 1;
>   END WHILE;
> END$$
> ```

Comment: Is there no `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE data` -- I wonder if the table was forced to be InnoDB.

Comment: The table DEFINITION is stored in the Data Dictionary and this could be the reason you observe IO.

Answer (score 2):

Look `SHOW PROCESSLIST` - the most time the process state is 'waiting for handler commit'.

If your server version is 8 use recursive CTE instead:

```sql
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `datetime`,`value`,`channel`)
WITH recursive 
cte AS (select 1 i
        union all
        select i+1 from cte where i <= 600000)
select i, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 01:00:00')+FLOOR(RAND()*31536000)),
       ROUND(RAND()*100,2),
       i
FROM cte;
```

If you have 5+ server, use synthetic number tables:

```sql
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `datetime`,`value`,`channel`)
select i, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 01:00:00')+FLOOR(RAND()*31536000)),
       ROUND(RAND()*100,2),
       i
FROM (  SELECT 1+d1.num+d2.num*10+d3.num*100+d4.num*1000+d5.num*10000+d6.num*100000 i
        FROM (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) d1,
             (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) d2,
             (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) d3,
             (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) d4,
             (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) d5,
             (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) d6
      ) d0;
```

At the same system (server version 8.0.18):

- your procedure - over 20 min. (killed after 5 min, 122k records were inserted)
- insert with CTE - 3.10 sec.
- insert with synth. tables - 4.08 sec.

Comment: Perfect answer, anyway the question still open: why I see the I/O? it should be "In memory".. When I restart the server the data is gone, so it's truly in memory.

Comment: @YuriLansberg *why I see the I/O? it should be "In memory"* Table locks, which occures each separate INSERT... transactions (each separate INSERT is a transaction) with their undo buffer... and everything must be written into system tablespace...

Comment: @Akina - I don't think "undo" is the answer ---  `ENGINE=MEMORY` is non-transactional.

Comment: @RickJames 'waiting for handler commit' state means that there are transactions during the process. I don't know where the term "commit" can be applied without reference to transactions.

Comment: @Akina - _Perhaps_ the "handler" tells the Engine that it is time for a "commit".  Then the Engine has the option to do something with it (as in InnoDB), or simply ignore it (MyISAM or MEMORY).  That is, the "handler", which is engine-agnostic, does not care.

Comment: @RickJames Single query in most cases is a transaction, even on non-transactional engines. If any error during execution occures then all statement effect must be rolled back - and this process needs in transactional mechanizm. Of course there is a lot of exclusions (for example, LOAD DATA INFILE, where the data part already inserted before the error occures is not removed). In shown OP's code each separate INSERT is a transaction, which must be fixed after all checkings which may detect potential execution error. I think that process state waits for that fixing is possibe.

Comment: @Akina - With InnoDB, by default (autocommit=ON), a single query is a complete transaction.  But with MyISAM and MEMORY, there is no concept of a transaction.  More specifically, if you crash in the middle of a multi-row `UPDATE` or `DELETE` (on MyISAM or MEMORY), no rollback will occur, and you have no automated way of repairing the half-finished update/delete.

Comment: @Akina - Some clustering setups, even with InnoDB, `LOAD DATA` will be chunked rather than swamping the undo log (etc).

Comment: Guys, when I shut down server: all data is gone. So no rollback, transaction or some other such staff should be involved. This is very easily reproducible on your end. The server just writes to disk for every statement. If this is the situation: It's definitely bug. It's impossible to use this feature in such way, I'll move to MSSQL or Oracle. They do it much better. May I change some setting to improve it ?

Comment: @YuriLansberg Memory table is ALWAYS truncated during restart! See engine description... If you need it to be like-static then you may generate it during server start, or store its data copy in static table, and copy data back into memory table during start.

Comment: @YuriLansberg - What?  Are you copying the table to disk repeatedly?  It would be _much_ faster to let InnoDB take care of such internally.  No data loss on shutdown or even power failure.  MEMORY specifically says you _will lose data_ on shutdown.

Comment: Guys, I am just trying to describe my setup. If you don't have any other good ideas regarding setting that might improve one by one insert without write to disk: let's close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

If, for unknown reasons, the table is really `ENGINE=InnoDB`, then you can speed it up this way:

```
BEGIN;
CALL generate_data()
COMMIT.
```

If you have overcommitted RAM, then the I/O is caused by swapping.  To fix this, please provide:  RAM size, other apps running, `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, and any other settings you increased.  We can advise then.

**Later...**

This technique did not help performance.

I tested the SP in various versions of MySQL and MariaDB -- It is slow *only* in 8.0.  *Please file a bug report* at https://bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: No swapping for sure, I have gigs of free ram and no swap defined.

Comment: Some benchmarks have shown InnoDB to be faster than MEMORY.  I don't have details, nor do I remember if they were doing the same thing you are doing.

Comment: I disagree, those benchmark are based on parallel in-memory table updates. I always update my in-memory table in 1 thread. The most important for me is select, that runs very fast as it's no chance to read from the disk.

Comment: @YuriLansberg - File a bug report (see addition to my Answer).  And, sure, the benchmarks were probably multi-threaded.